# Accessing javaFX elements from Java Code (outside controller classes)

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

Is it possible to edit/access javaFX elements (such as Buttons, Labels, etc.) in java code which is NOT the controller class?

I have written an entire program in java and want to make a GUI for it in javaFX (using Scene Builder). Since the entire code ALREADY is written in Java classes outside the FXML-controller class, is it possible to access elements like "Labels" inside my already written classes?

All I want to do is use this code outside the FXML-controller class:
label1.setText("Something");

So it updates on the GUI.

If not, it is a very time-consuming process to implement my java code in the FXML-controller class.

Comment: Call class from FXML and pass the elements instance as constructor argument?

Comment: Have you written all of the GUI logic without using JavaFX?  If so, then your going to have to re-write that to use JavaFX.  If it's just your business logic, then there's no reason you can't create a wrapper for it that translates between JavaFX, and non FX code.

Comment: I am not sure to understand. You can put accessors like `Label getLabel()` in your controller to access it elsewhere. Or you can call other classes methods from your controller by passing your components as parameters.

Comment: Frank that is correct understanding of my problem. I actually have not learned about wrapper yet. But I will do that asap.

Comment: I don't really understand the problem. Can't you just pass a reference to an instance of your existing class to the controller, and access it from the controller that way? Can you post an example to clarify what you mean?

Comment: Specifically, you really don't want to expose the details of your UI outside the controller. (If you do, when your boss walks into your office and says "please change this text field to a drop down box", it'll turn into a nightmare.) So if there are data that you have in another class that you need to display in your UI, you would make the instance of that class available to your controller, and your controller would be responsible for updating the UI with the data in your existing class. Your existing class is essentially (part of) the "model" (the "M" in "MVC" or "MVP").

Comment: I guess the other option you might consider, depending on how everything's set up, would be to make your existing class the controller. It's unlikely that's a particularly good design choice, though...

Answer (score 0):

So I think your solution depends on how safe you need your information to be when interfacing with the FX GUI.  If you are OK providing your data directly to the controller, then I'd suggest simply passing your data object into the controller's constructor and storing a reference to it locally.  You can then use any getters/setters from the data object to populate your GUI, or update the model.

```
 public class Controller {
      private Object dataObject;

      public Controller(Object dataObject) {
           this.dataObject = dataObject;
      }
 }
```

However, if you want to protect your data, and prevent the GUI from directly modifying or interacting with it - you'll need to use a wrapper that protects your information.

```
 public class Wrapper {
      private Object dataObject;

      public Controller(Object dataObject) {
                this.dataObject = dataObject;
      }

      // allowable function call
      public Object functionOne() {
           return dataObject.functionOne();
      }
 }
```

You only need to implement functions in the wrapper that are directly needed by the GUI, thus preventing calls into your data object that you think should be restricted from the GUI.

Your controller then becomes:

```
 public class Controller {
      private Wrapper dataObject;

      public Controller(Wrapper dataObject) {
           this.dataObject = dataObject;
      }
 }
```

Comment: While this answer is helpful, since the default mechanisms for loading FXML only work when the controller has a no-arg constructor, you should probably show how to load the FXML when the controller doesn't have a default constructor to make it properly useful. (Also, you named the constructor for `Wrapper` incorrectly...)

Comment: Thank you very much, it will take a while for me to comprehend this new information, but now I have something to work with! (btw, safety is not a priority in this case)